# Using GitLab Webhooks with Jenkins locally

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, continuous-integration, webhooks

I keep running into the same error with my setup. I want to configure jenkins and gitlab to automatically build some code on push events. I´m running the docker version of gitlab, while jenkins is running on localhost.
I tried setting up GitLab Jenkins Integration according to the documentation but the connection is continuously refused and I am asked to check my jenkins details(which are 100% correct, since Im using the standard configuration.)
When I tried setting up the webhook manually I´m confronted with a 422 error:

[Picture of the response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9PsG.png)

I think that this problem might be connected to the fact that I´m trying to set up everything locally. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem was due to the fact that both services where setup on localhost and talking to the same interface. I dockered both applications and now webhooks are working.

Answer (score 0):

because you may write `0.0.0.0/your-webhook-url` in gitlab. You have to write what your ip in the local network exactly at there. I confront this f**king issue, stuck me a long time.

`ifconfig | grep inet` to check your ip.